# For $f,f_1 \ldots f_n \in L^1(X,M,\mu,\mathbb{R})$ suppose that $\sum_{n}\int |f_n-f| d\mu \lt \infty$ . Show that $f_n \to f ,\mu-$a.e

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measure space. For $f,f_1 \ldots f_n \in L^1(X,M,\mu,\mathbb{R})$ suppose that $\sum_{n}\int |f_n-f| d\mu \lt \infty$ . Show that $f_n \to f, \mu-$a.e

This is a problem from Cohn's Measure Theory (Section 3.1, Q4).

My try:

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be fixed. Suppose that $E_n^{\epsilon}=\{x \in X: |f_n(x)-f(x)| \ge \epsilon\}$. Then $$\infty \gt \sum \int|f_n-f|d\mu \ge \sum_{n}\int_{E_n}|f_n-f| \ge \epsilon\sum_{n}\mu(E_n^{\epsilon})$$
Thus $$\sum_{n} \mu(E_n^{\epsilon}) \lt \infty$$
Then for any $\delta \gt 0$, then there exists a $n_0(\delta)$ such that $\forall k \ge n_0(\delta)$ we have $$\sum_{j \ge n_0(\delta)}\mu(E_j^{\epsilon}) \lt \delta$$ Suppose that $$E_{\delta}^{\epsilon}=\cup_{j \ge n_0(\delta)}E_j^{\epsilon}, E^{\epsilon}=\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}E_{\frac{1}{k}}^{\epsilon} (\text{I am taking $\delta=\frac{1}{k}$)}$$ Then  $\mu(E^{\epsilon})=0$. As suggested in the answer, I am getting rid of the dependence on $\epsilon$. Let $$E=\cup_{j \in \mathbb{N}}E^{\frac{1}{j}}$$ It is clear that $\mu(E)=0$. Now let $\eta \gt 0$ be fixed. Then there is $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{1}{i} \lt \eta$. Then for $x \not \in E, x \not\in E^{\dfrac{1}{i}}$ which means that $x \not \in E_\dfrac{1}{k_1}^{\dfrac{1}{i}}, \forall j \ge n_0\left(\dfrac{1}{k_1}\right)$ .Thus $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \lt \dfrac{1}{i} \lt \eta, \forall n \ge n_0\left(\frac{1}{k_1}\right)$.

I am sorry. The notation is a mess. I will edit it afterwards.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks ok to me, with one subtle point: the exceptional set $E$ depends on $\varepsilon$, so you should let $\varepsilon\to 0$ along some sequence to conclude that $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere, using the fact that a countable union of null sets is a null set.

By the way, the middle part of your argument is similar to the proof of the Borel-Cantelli lemma, which is definitely a result worth knowing.

Comment: I was thinking about the same. I don't know what Borel-Cantelli lemma is. I will look into it. I can take $\epsilon=\dfrac {1}{2^n} $ and then take $E = \cup_n E_{\dfrac {1}{2^n}} $??

Comment: Sure, or just $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{n}$. The Borel-Cantelli lemma states that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)<\infty$, then $\mu(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\cup_{k=n}^{\infty}E_k)=0$.